# Adding a highscore to a Game in Asp.Net MVC, and make it display in the Game Details

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I have this Game Model

```
    public class Game
{
    [NotMapped]
    public List<HighScores> HighScores { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And this HighScores Model:

```
public class HighScores
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Game")]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GameId")]
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
}
```

I Create the games from the Database, but i create the Highscores via a Create method in The HighScoresController, like this:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var games = _context.games.ToList();
        ViewData["GameId"] = new SelectList(games, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(HighScores highScores)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var game = _context.games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == highScores.GameId);

            highScores.Game = game; 
            _context.highscores.Add(highScores);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var gamesList = _context.games.ToList();
        ViewData["GameId"] = new SelectList(gamesList, "Id", "Name", highScores.GameId);
        return View(highScores);
    }
```

And this is the Create View Component Code:

```
   @model HighScores

<form method="post" asp-controller="HighScores" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Game" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="GameId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GameId">
            <option value="">-- Select a game --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

For some reason when i hit submit and inspect the highscore, the `GameId` is correct but the `Game` is null, so the highscore is not created.

It works when i create the Highscore from the database, but not from the form.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `HighScores`, The `Game` property is `Non-nullable`  by default. In your Create view, You just pass data to `GameId` property, `Game` property is null. So when the code access into Create HttpPost method, `ModelState.IsValid` will be false because `Game` property is null. You just need to add `?` to make `Game` property become `nullable`:

```
[ForeignKey("GameId")]
public virtual Game? Game { get; set; }
```

Then the highscore can be created successfully in your httppost action.